# How do I make my text editor's window transparent?

Tags: wxpython

I'm working on a text editor and I would like the menu to have a menu option to make the window transparent such as [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfdey.png) Here is my text editor:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wx.Window` has a `SetTransparent` function, as well as a `CanSetTransparent` function to test availability.
0 (zero) is totally transparent - 255 is totally opaque

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.Trans = wx.Button(self, -1,"Transparent")
        self.Trans.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnTrans)
        self.t_state = False
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.control,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        sizer.Add(self.Trans,0,0,0)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

        #self.OnTrans(None) #Initial Start-up in transparent mode

    def OnTrans(self, event):
        if not self.t_state:
            self.SetTransparent(200)
        else:
            self.SetTransparent(255)
        self.t_state = not self.t_state

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image][image]